# Can I make PowerBI report re-pull data from the data source when the value of the slicer changes? (they way SSRS parameters work)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, slicers

I am new to PowerBI and have one report, which I would like to work similarly to the SSRS. When the value of the slicer changes, I would like to re-pull data from my data source for further analysis. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is called [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-directquery). Here is [a list of data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources), which supports DirectQuery mode.

Comment: Thank you, my sources ARE configured for "Direct Query" , but what I am after is triggering the query to re-run when the slicer is changed. Currently, it simply filters/slices the previously pulled data. I basically want to link my slicer to the query parameters, so that when I change the slicer value, it gets passed to the query parameter and query re-runs. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm afraid Power BI doesn't work this way. The proper way is to implement the logic, which is currently in your database, in Power BI using M and DAX.